# Caching a "deep" JSON object using GUIDs as keys

Tags: javascript, json, caching, recursion, large-data

So I have a large, simple object that was loaded in from a JSON file in my JavaScript application.

This file has about 9 MB of data (should be lower once I minify it though) and is a nested structure like so:

```
{
    "guid": "guid 1 here",
    "children": [
        {
            "guid": "guid 2 here",
            "other": "properties",
            "here": true,
            "children": [
                {
                    "guid": "guid 3 here",
                    ...
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I am not aware of the depth of this object and I need to use a generic function that locates a node based on its GUID property regardless of its depth in the tree. This recursive function (which I know could be optimized using a while loop instead of recursion, but regardless it is expensive) is slow.

I am wondering if initially after loading this object, I create a cache structure like this:

```
var cache = {
    "guid 1 here": [reference to object],
    "guid 2 here": [reference to object],
    "guid 3 here": [reference to object]
};
```

This, I would think, would make finding objects quicker, since I can just say

```
var node = cache[guid];
```

However, would this actually end up being a performance increase, or could this potentially cause memory problems? I've never dealt with a variable like `cache`, where there would potentially be hundreds of thousands of properties.

Would this help or hinder the situation?

Thanks for your advice as always, SO, you guys are amazing.

Comment: @EdBayiates: No, an array is useless here. guids are not array indices, and even if they were then the array would be very sparse (which is not a good idea)

Comment: If I use an array, won't I have to iterate through each item until I find the one with the GUID I want? `var result; for (var i = 0; i < cache.length; ++i) { if (cache[i].guid == search_guid) { result = cache[i]; break; } }`

Comment: Objects with properties are an associative array.  Sorry you had the correct syntax above.  All JavaScript objects are stored as arrays internally, which is why cache[guid] works.  I edited my answer to update the terminology.

Comment: @EdBayiates: …an associative array without an order, which leaves a hash map. Whether they are implemented as arrays or (more likely) not doesn't matter. `cache[guid]` is not an array syntax, it's an *object* property access.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, yes, I updated my answer for this.  The point is that cache[guid] is far more performant than looping through the data.

Comment: Okay, so I just want to be sure -- what I have now is, verbatim, what I should have, i.e. `cache = { "guid here": object reference here , ... }`?

Comment: Yes.  That is varbatim what you should use to get the best performance without adding a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made the right choice.

Object references are reasonably small. Even with thousands of objects such an object (which is stored internally as an array-like hash map) should not increase memory use significantly -- a few MB max.  When you create your cache you are not making a copy of the objects.  You are putting a *pointer* into the object (array style) that points to the object in the structure you've deserialized.  So you aren't making a second copy of all the data.  Just a cache of GUID and pointer.

This cache method uses a great feature of JavaScript, which is that the property indices are kept sorted internally.  Lookups by property index (e.g., `cache[guid]` ) are then performed with a binary search.  That will be orders of magnitude faster than a loop or recursive search on unsorted data.

Comment: OP is not using an array for the cache?

Comment: `[]` *is* an object operator?

Comment: You weren't talking of literals, but of lookup operators.

Answer (score 1):

> However, would this actually end up being a performance increase

Probably. Having a large constant-access data structure (even if costly to build) is generally faster than repeatedly iterating all "hundreds of thousands" of nodes.

If you could however optimize the recursive lookup function, e.g. by deriving the parent node's location from the guid, it might not be a that large benefit.

> or could this potentially cause memory problems?

Yes, large data structures can always cause memory problems on low-memory devices. It shouldn't be a problem however if you don't have any problems with your original JSON data.

Comment: Bergi, his cache uses pointers.  Not a second copy of the data.

Comment: @EdBayiates: I wasn't talking about copies of the nodes?